# RailsTutorial.org Learning Rails 5.3.4 Layout link test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

The links in the header won't work. The code from the header file is below.

What am I doing wrong? Where's my mistake? Please help.

Here's the code for the app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb file:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse"> <br/>
  <div class="container"> <br/>
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %> <br/>
    <nav> <br/>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <br/>
        <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li> <br/>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li> <br/>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li> <br/>
      </ul> <br/>
    </nav> <br/>
  </div> <br/>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you please add **config/routes.rb** file in your question? I have a feeling you didnt specify your routes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what your routes.rb file looks like. Your above header file looks fine to me. It must be wrong routing.

I have just looked at the tutorial website you are using and it seems the problem is that you are missing the following two lines of code in your **config/routes.rb** file...

```
root          'static_pages#home'
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @TimKos. I found the error. There were two issues: 1 I was missing an '=' in the application.html.erb file and 2 there header code wasn't removed from the application.html.erb file.